# Globally unique option field numbers for protobufs

Tags: protocol-buffers

In the protobuf documentation (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions) it says this about custom options:

> One last thing: Since custom options are extensions, they must be
>   assigned field numbers like any other field or extension. In the
>   examples above, we have used field numbers in the range 50000-99999.
>   This range is reserved for internal use within individual
>   organizations, so you can use numbers in this range freely for
>   in-house applications. If you intend to use custom options in public
>   applications, however, then it is important that you make sure that
>   your field numbers are globally unique. To obtain globally unique
>   field numbers, please send a request to
>   protobuf-global-extension-registry@google.com. Simply provide your
>   project name (e.g. Object-C plugin) and your project website (if
>   available). Usually you only need one extension number.

Why do the options field numbers have to be globally unique for public applications? In what way can collisions be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, because you wouldn't know whether the data you get is correct.

The protobuf binary wire format *only* stores the field numbers and the payload (which is itself, for complex types, just field numbers and sub-payloads). There is no name data. So: when you store and retrieve an extension field, all you're saying is "fetch field {field number}, interpret it as {type}". If two different systems have extended *the same data* using *the same field number*, then you don't have any way of knowing whether the data you're fetching was *actually* in that format.

Normally this isn't a problem - as it is rare to conflict like this on the same data; but custom options are different! I'm a library author; I might want to add a custom option that my schema parsing tools recognize, by extending (say) `MessageOptions`. `MessageOptions` is the extension point for `DescriptorProto`, which is to say: that's what `option (foo) = "bar";` goes to inside a `message`.

To do that, I need to assign a number for `foo`. I choose `5000` arbitrarily (`MessageOptions` defines `extensions 1000 to max;`, so that's fine). All is good. My tooling works.

Unknown to me, *another* library author has chosen to do something similar and has *also* used 5000. Once the schema is compiled (by `protoc` or similar), *all I have is numbers*. If I ask for the data from field 5000, I don't know whether I'm getting my extension, or the other one. The meaning is lost. OK, *at a push* I could also check the `dependency` list on the `FileDescriptorProto`, but ... that's hit and miss.

I don't know whether the presense of value `1` in field `5000` is:

```
option (.mystuff.someext) = 1;
```

vs

```
option (.anotherlib.whatever) = -1; // stored as sint32
```

vs

```
option (.yetanother.library.option) = true;
```

If those extensions all have number 5000, they appear **identically** on the wire.